# Why am I not able to use Python 3 in a Crontab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, raspberry-pi3

As an example, I've placed a simple program on on the path home/pi to test.

My crontab script is

```
* * * * * /pi/testcron.py
```

and I haven`t got any results. I've tried other scripts -recommended here- but without success.

I appreciate any support I can receive.

Comment: What is in `testcron.py`? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Hello, thank you.   It is just a sample to test the cron execution.  It includes only a print instruction.  I have tried with other .py files without results.

Comment: You won't see the output of a `print` instruction that is executed through cron. See my answer below for more detail

Comment: Are you sure you want to accept this answer? It doesnt seem like your problem is resolved. By accepting an answer you are less likely to get new answers that may solve the issue you are having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like you're expecting to see output from the `print` function. The problem is, since cron is running the script in another shell/terminal, **you won't see `print` output even if it is running correctly**. For example, if you open up two terminal windows, and run your script manually in one window, you won't see your print output in the other. In order to leave a lasting effect, use a redirect for the print output. This will open a new file that you'll be able to inspect after the cronjob has run.

As others have said, you'll likely need to include the full path to your python installation. The common sys install path is `/usr/bin/python3`. So, you should do something like:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/testcron.py > /home/my_output.txt`

The last part `> /home/my_output.txt` will redirect the output of the `print` function to the file `/home/my_output.txt`. After the crontab runs, you should be able to open the file and the output of the `print` command.

**Please do not copy/paste this exactly as-is and expect it to work without doing some sanity checking! Make sure that the directories are correct!** For example, `/home/pi/testcron.py` should be the full path to your python file. We are just guessing at your file structure, we don't *know* what it looks like.

Comment: I'd like if the downvoter would please explain their rationale (i.e. what is incorrect or not useful about the answer). Then I can improve my future answers. I think it would be a nice feature if users were forced to leave comments upon downvoting.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I´ve tested the script using your suggestion to redirect the install path.  Unfortunately continues without running.  Only to clarify, the printing text file is for simplify the process.  What I am trying to run is a temperature measure, so I need to launch a python file periodically.  When I have used the crontab with this file I haven´t obtained any result.

Comment: Triple check those paths...cron is a very old and stable tool. I am certain the bug rests in your python code or in your crontab. does your python script output anything when you run it by hand?

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the python script you are testing with in your question.

Comment: Yes, it is a simple printing command. I have tested a printing sequence, due to at the beginning I tried a complex program to monitor a sensor, and it was failing.     print ("ok")

Comment: Thank you, mwm314.  In fact,  after several tries, I have finally fixed the cron script based on your suggestion.  I have resent the output to a .txt file to check out that the cron runs.  Now, I have been able to restructure the whole cron to make the program without problems.    I was becoming crazy regarding this matter.  Again,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Cron runs scripts using `sh` shell. It doesn't know about your python configuration. Put full path to python before your script.

```
* * * * * /path/to/python3/python/Python-3.6.1/python /home/pi/testcron.py
```

If you don't know python path, use `which python` to get it.

Comment: Thank you,  I have added the script * * * * * /usr/bin/python/Python-3.6.1/python /home/pi/testcron.py but it doesn´t run.  I have checked my path as you suggested.  I´m not sure my Python version is 3.6.1

Comment: @Fermar If that script is only printing some values, you won't see them in your shell. You have to redirect output to some file, like in *mwm314* answer.

Answer (score 0):

your program was located in home/pi, so your Crontab script should be (you should enter the full path)

```
* * * * *  /**home**/pi/testcron.py
```

To be sure about your full path, write **pwd** in terminal and press enter.

```
$pwd
/home/pi
```